# Retrieve date from column index position in pandas and paste in PyQt

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, qlineedit

I want to retrieve the date of one index position of a Pandas data frame and paste it into the LineEdit of a PyQt Application.

What I have so far is:

```
    purchase = sales [['Total','Date']]
    pandas_value = purchase.iloc[-1:]['Date'] # last position of the "Date" column
    pyqt_value = str(pandas_value)

    # This returns : 

    67   2016-10-20
    Name: Data, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The entire output appears in the LineEdit as : 67   2016-10-20 Name: Data, dtype: datetime64[ns]

I have also tried converting the date, to no avail:

```
    pandas_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Is there a way to retrieve and paste just the date like : 2016-10-20 ?

Or better : Is there a way to retrieve any value as a string from any index position in pandas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
        Date         a
0 2016-01-01  0.228208
1 2016-01-02  0.695593
2 2016-01-03  0.493608
3 2016-01-04  0.728678
4 2016-01-05  0.369823
5 2016-01-06  0.336615
6 2016-01-07  0.012200
7 2016-01-08  0.481646
8 2016-01-09  0.773467
9 2016-01-10  0.550114

In [38]: df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Date')].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[38]: '2016-01-10'
```

Comment: Working perfectly ...many thanks ... I'm still learning Pandas and slowly getting the hang of it. It's great fun ..

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` returns it as `Series` which is like a `list` (normally it keeps one row or one column of data) so you have to use index to get value. You `Series` has only one value so you can use index `[0]` (or maybe `[67]` because your text shows value `67` as index)

```
 pyqt_values = str(panda_values[0])
```

Comment: Furas, thanks for your suggestion. Using [0] returns : 
KeyError: 0. Using [67] gets me: argument 1 has unexpected type 'Timestamp'. I also need [-1], because I need the value of the last row.

Comment: I have played around with the suggestion you have posted the other day, and it would actually work only after converting the value to monetary. I still don't fully understand Pandas and just send this as feedback.